# What to do when I feel that someone is stalking me?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes, etiquette, harassment

There is a particular user that follows me around (SO) and wants to be a "cool kid" and prove me wrong on every occasion he gets... It's becoming really annoying and I want to avoid having extended discussions in the comments section *fighting* over why I was right and why I think he is wrong. Even though he tries to keep it constructive most of the time it's slicking off topic and the constructiveness evolves into an unnecessary and primarily opinion based discussion...

I really don't mind the downvotes when I am wrong, but that person is just being too picky - as most of the comments are **not** about the **quality, correctness of my answer** but a matter of **his preference**...

When I think I can provide a better answer to a question than an existing one then I go for it and give an alternative but I don't downvote ***correct answers*** just because they are *different* to my solution.

Sample Q:

> How do I multiply 3 numbers to get 12?

Sample A:

> You can do 2*6*1.

comment:

> -1 because 1*12*1 would be better.

Ok, so one option is to completely ignore it as that's fine.. but how do I get him to stop following me.. It makes me to want to quit participating on SO because of the annoyance.

How would you deal with it?

Comment: You have two options: ignore it, or call the cavalry (== mods).

Comment: Flag his posts, explain what's going on.

Comment: and how are mods going to stop it?

Comment: @mehow - we could ultimately suspend them - if we thought it was warranted.

Comment: Targeting a specific user is explicitly disallowed, so if they agree that is the case, they might suspend the user or at least give them a warning.

Comment: @ChrisF what about removing a handful of their troublesome comments for a start? in my experience, users discovering that their comments are not ignored by someone having power to delete, typically tend to cool off

Comment: How certain are you this user is specifically targeting you? Is that user being picky about posts by others as well?

Comment: @gnat - I should have said "ultimately". But, yes flagging the comments as "not constructive" or even "other" would be a good start.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can I not be certain when I checked the activity tab of that user he didn't seem so picky about any other answers.

Comment: @mehow: All I asked was a confirmation that you had checked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes I checked.

Comment: If I read the signs right: You have *silver* badges in [tag:excel], [tag:vba], and [tag:vba-excel], whereas your alleged 'stalker' has the same badges in *gold*. That means your fields of expertise overlap, and *that*, in turn, means you are quite likely to run in to each other on questions tagged with any or all of these.

Comment: @Jongware yes it's true that we run in to each other quite often however I am not complaining about seeing the user "too often". The root of the question is based entirely on the fact that the user argues over things that are unnecessary and worthless mentioning or purely a matter of preference.

Comment: Just went over part of your recent history and I can't say he's stalking rather than commenting his preferences when he stumbles upon something he would do differently. He's not going after your answers as far as I can see.

Comment: For every communication problem there are two parties who are both at fault. He's making mistakes here - so are you. Probably, yours is to engage in discussion.

Comment: That's like saying "+1, but only if you add 3*4*1 to your answer." Quite ridiculous.

Comment: I think what you actually need to do is stop preemptively following him around.

Comment: Is he the same who went on down voting spree on you? Those questions and answers don't deserve downvotes IMHO. Could the moderators look into it?

Comment: @LazyNinja. No it certainly wasn't me. The mistake I made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380886/1004-error-no-cells-were-found-easy-solution/25381059#comment39586731_25381059) was to take the trouble to explain a downvote. Lesson learned. I'm not going comment further on a futile "you said/I said" path that will benefit no-one.

Comment: @brettdj As I can see now, you are a 26k expert, so I doubt you will be involved in such behavior. And I doubt, that you are trying to harass the OP owner. Since you are here, maybe it will be beneficial for all of us if you write your side of the story.

Comment: -1 Clearly the best factorization would be a product of prime numbers, `12 = 2*2*3`, which is unique (except for the order of the factors and multiplication of unities). [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). I'm joking :)

Answer (score 55):

I think I know the user to whom you are referring, as I have seen both of you getting into unnecessary discussions a number of times. Here is my take on it:

Do not involve the mods for such petty issues. They already have their plates full with more important things.

You both are knowledgeable experts. If I were you, I would get into a chat room with that person and thrash it out. Make use of the wonderful tool (chat facility): I have done it in the past and it has worked wonders. You **both** are, in my opinion, mature individuals who can help lot of Stack Overflow users with your knowledge. :)

After the chat, if you still feel that it is not working out, then involve the mods.

Comment: Eh, I think it's fine to ask mods for help.  This kind of thing is very much within their purview.  They can always contact the other member via a private message and ask them to stop being annoying, if not in so many words.

Comment: ^ What @Will said but just be sure to try and handle this on your own first by, well, simply not engaging. If it continues over a significant period of time, go ahead and let us know. Just remember we aren't your nannies and don't come to us every time someone says something to you you don't like.

Comment: I echo @BoltClock's comments. Mods are not nannies! + 1 on that!

Answer (score 48):

My suggestion: walk away. Don't let this develop into a feud.

I looked into this, and I see no malicious targeting of comments at you. You both simply frequent the same tags, and you're both subject matter experts, so you will tend to run into each other just by chance. The few comments I saw that they left on your posts were about the technical content of those posts, not you personally.

They downvoted your answer, left a comment explaining what was wrong with it, and you lashed out at them for it. I can say that you didn't help things by calling them "ignorant" in one of your replies (which I've since removed). As an experienced user, you know that you can't take downvotes personally, and what happened here is exactly why we don't make comments mandatory for downvotes.

Nothing they've posted in comments over the last couple of months appears to be rude or abusive, so I see no need to take action here.

Comment: While I think this is actually useful information, I'm not sure I like the answer of "Walk Away".  From StackOverflow?  And lose a valuable user?

Answer (score 11):

First off, do not assume he is stalking you.

In this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12796973/revisions) for example, he's the one who was there first, and you're the one who corrected him with an incorrect edit. So if his imagination was as vivid as yours, he could definitely say that you're the one who's stalking him, and he would be technically correct (not that he said anything of the kind).

> ...that person is
>   just being too picky - as most of the comments are not about the
>   quality, correctness of my answer but a matter of his preference...

Yes, but his preference has a predictable logic to it. He always wants the most efficient solution or the most perfect solution to a given problem (even if efficiency or perfection aren't even requirements of the question in the first place).

So in that sense, he's a perfectionist, or he has OCD, and the example you gave is not something representative of what he would have said.

> but I don't downvote correct answers just because they are different
>   to my solution.

If you go through his posting history, you'll see that he does this to **everybody**, and I really do mean **everybody**! So again, his posts really have nothing to do with you, and everything to do with himself.

And if you're lucky enough to get a -1 on an answer because of him, note that someone will probably correct it to a 0 to counter balance his vote. And the way StackOverflow works, that means you'll gain an extra +8 in reputation because of him (because one downvote counts as -2 points and one upvote counts as +10 points).

The same goes for comments. If one of his comments indicates that he downvoted an answer of yours because he feels your solution was not the most optimal one (despite the fact that it works perfectly well). It's very likely that one or more users will upvote your answer just to try to counterbalance his single negative vote.

Comment: ++ "So if his imagination was as vivid as yours"

Comment: No, this would have been the correct edit: "Does anyone have a VBA function which can calculate the Excel's column letter when given the column row?"

Comment: And not: "Does anyone have a VBA function which can calculate the Excel's column letter when given the column row for?" The "for" here makes no sense.