# What to do when you have a Stack Overflow Stalker

Tags: discussion, harassment

I'm dealing with someone that notoriously answers questions on a topic with criticisms and no help at all.  I flagged his comments on my last question because as per usual none of them were helpful and he seemed more interested in arguing and his comments were removed by the moderator.  He is now stalking our SO account and down voting our answers and sending us messages through our website.  We don't really care about the loss of points because we get paid in dollars and not in points.

I was under the impression that the purpose of this site was to engage in legitimate and serious resolution to programming issues.  This should not be allowed.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Here is the message:

> Surprise DOUCHBAG!  I really don’t care if you think my answers are correct or not     but I am going to make sure that NO ONE pays attention to your answers!

Comment: [Related post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269172/what-to-do-when-i-feel-that-someone-is-stalking-me)

Comment: You have only two visible downvotes on your account in the last week, and both of them are on the same post (meaning they couldn't be cast by the same person), so unless there are deleted posts he couldn't have downvoted you more than once. Also, it looks from the comments on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25572053/712603) like there might be context you aren't sharing.

Comment: HI @DavidRobinson.  The user down voted on that answer and then sent us a message thru our site informing us that he would continue to do so.  I guess that is his plan to keep us from using the forum.  It won't work.

Comment: I can't speak to the outside harassment you may be seeing, but your suspicions on SO aren't evident.

Comment: @ThesisDesign When you said "down voting our answers," it gave the misleading impression he was casting multiple downvotes targeting you (which is prohibited on Stack Overflow). Casting a single downvote is not in any way harassment. You might want to remove that part from the question here.

Comment: This chaos happening is all because downvotes are visible like **-1**, **-2** etc.. human nature can't be changed and humans will always be bothered by negativity directed to them no matter what you tell them and what rules you put up

Comment: You could also share the messages you've received: it can't hurt to be more specific, [and it has happened before on the site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf)

Comment: I'd propose to hide negative votes in the UI but not in the database

Comment: Hi again @DavidRobinson he down voted and sent us an email stating that he would continue to down vote all of our answers.  This is a personal vendetta because we did not accept his answer to one of out previous questions.

Comment: I don't know if this was already proposed

Comment: I mean that this will be useful also for peeps like Thes is Design

Comment: @ThesisDesign Perhaps you could share the specific contents of the email in your question, as [this user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf) did?

Comment: @DavidRobinson wouldnt that constitue invasion of privacy?

Comment: @Moderateur No. When you send an email to someone (especially a hostile one) you do not have the right to demand that they do not share it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson ok just saying I thought it was otherwise

Comment: @Moderateur, contacting *anyone* from a public site and assuming privacy is ignorant.

Comment: and many people arent even under usa jurisdiction so

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I was not questioning the fact rather the legality :-)

Comment: Okay @DavidRobinson  I have edited the post to include the email.  Is there an SO address that I can forward the actual email to?

Comment: @ThesisDesign there is contact form on bottom of page or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact.

Comment: looking at this "douchebag" message I can see he's great in employing psychological warfare

Comment: @Moderateur yeah he's as skilled at threats as he is at answering questions on this topic.  I don't know there doesn't seem to be much that we can do.  But we aren't going to stop using the forum.  It's been a great tool for us so far.

Comment: You can sent a message to team@stackoverflow.com as suggested by [Jaydles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf#comment52051_262202) here with all the contents of the message. I'd recommend you edit your question to focus on the threatening message itself. It's misleading to say that he's downvoted your answers (plural)- this seems more like a threat of stalking than actual stalking.

Comment: Hi @DavidRobinson the comments are coming in so fast that I missed the comment from Jaydles.  Thanks I'll do that right now.  Threat of stalking or continued stalking really seems like the same thing atleast from our end.  I don't really understand why someone would put this type of effort into this.

Comment: Jaydles's comment wasn't on this question, it was on a different one. My point about the difference is that as of yet he hasn't downvoted any of your answers except (presumably) the one.

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes I know but since he told us that was his plan in our book he is a stalker and it isn't what the forum is for.

Comment: @ThesisDesign I agree. he should check himself at some psychiatry counsel or practice yoga dunno

Comment: @Moderateur if he puts this kind of time into attacking people because of his ego I am sure that he has more than one account on here.  Anyhow we're going to forward the email to the SO team and see what happens.

Comment: Not that it matters, but the user in question (judging from context) doesn't even have a Meta Stack Overflow account, meaning he couldn't have cast downvotes on this question.

Comment: @ThesisDesign That's why I suggested he checks himself out or practice yoga for anger management. I'm sure he's reading this

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'm not sure, maybe he's another account

Comment: @DavidRobinson I really don't know how the account structure works on here but he sent us inappropriate external mail.  I'm sure this loser has more than one account.  And we would prefer that he take his crazy somewhere else.  So we'll forward the message to SO and see what they can do.

Comment: Hopefully the email address that he used to send the message is attached to an SO account.

Comment: You think he possesses multiple additional accounts, each of them with greater than 125 reputation, and has been using them to check Meta Stack Overflow and downvote your question, even though he has never used Meta SO with his main account and indeed hasn't been seen on SO in six hours?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I know someone who did. actually.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I really haven't put much thought into the how because I don't think like a stalker and I don't use my time for this type of stuff.  What I know is some freak loser got upset because we didn't accept his answer and is crossing the line.  We use this forum professionally to ask for help and give help because that is what it is for.  Our experience on SO has been great until now.  But we aren't going anywhere.  We just needed some direction on the best way to get rid of this person

Comment: @ThesisDesign "We".. is that a shared account? in that case I suggest doing separate accounts because sharing an account is **forbidden** by SO rules

Comment: Hi @Moderateur when I say "We" I mean "Thesis".  I'm the only user on the account but we generally ask and answer questions as a group.  We're a co-op.

Comment: ouch 4 downvotes... what is going on with the community mentality now? this is a righteous question and is actually part of an emerging problem in this community...

Comment: @Moderateur I have no idea.  There should be an age limit in here.  I have to focus on wrapping a project.  I'm more interested in dollars than points.  I don't think any of these people down voting even have a bank account.

Comment: `What to do when you have a Stack Overflow Stalker`, well, you'll gain exclusive access to the *Fight Club*, enjoy! :)

Comment: I'm one of the people who downvoted, and I shared my reason [above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270229/what-to-do-when-you-have-a-stack-overflow-stalker?noredirect=1#comment87405_270229) (and in other comments since). I felt that the post was misleading in saying "downvoting our answers" when only one answer had been downvoted. Serial downvoting (which does resemble StackOverflow stalking) is an issue that people here take seriously, so it's misleading to describe yourself as a victim of it when you're not. I've suggested that you edit it multiple times, but you haven't.

Comment: @DavidRobinson you are entitled to your opinion but there is nothing misleading about it.  The entire scenario is described as it happened and we did edit the post to include the message.  And again we really don't care about down votes because we live in the real world.  We have actual projects to work on and actual money to make.  We use this forum constructively and others do not.  It's pretty simple.  We forwarded the email to the SO team and hopefully that will be the end of it because we don't care to squabble with some child that thinks that trolling for points means more than helping.

Comment: @DavidRobinson if you are a moderator should be able to see the history on our account and the comments made by that user that were deleted from our question before.  That should make the situation clearer for you.  If you are not part of the SO team then we hope that they will take the email that we forwarded to them and deal with it appropriately.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidRobinson What Thes is Design said and that you're the one stalking right now downvoting, even if it's your (flawed) opinion.

Comment: @ThesisDesign He's no moderator ;-) Moderators have a diamond next to their username.

Comment: @Moderateur yes apparently this is now an argument over the definition of stalking/harassment.  This is insane and ridiculous.  The forum is being misused and we asked for help.  End of story.  I don't think that the police treat someone that shows up on your doorstep and tells you they are going to harass you until you move any differently than someone that does is 30 days in a row and if he thinks I'm wrong maybe he should try it out to test the definition.  He can see if they accept SO points for bail.

Comment: I have no clue what happened outside the site. But there is *zero evidence* the user has done anything improper here. In fact, there is some contravening evidence... I say this because that other user has been revealed indirectly here, and I don't want people assuming too much.

Comment: @AndrewBarber we have forwarded the message to team@stackoverflow.com as suggested earlier in this thread.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewBarber there is no contravening evidence.  If you look at the entire picture the start of this can be traced back to a question that we posted that received non-answers from this user that we reported. Those comments were removed by a moderator after we reported them.  Thankfully we did get the answer we needed from a real professional that actually contributes positively to the forum.  We didn't accept his answer which wasn't an answer at all and then we get attacked.  We are thankful for the assistance that ChrisF offered us and again the email has been forwarded.

Comment: So, I have you on record: a user posting something that is "not an answer" is what triggered this? Because your response was way out of line to it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Whatever the trigger may have been **the OP was stalked off-site**.

Comment: @Moderateur I'm not in the least convinced of that. *Not in the smallest degree*. I will be very, very surprised if that's true, given what I've seen here.

Comment: Well @AndrewBarber prepare to be blown away.  And we aren't convinced in the smallest degree that anything will actually done given what we have seen here.  We'll appeal on the Filemaker questions because there is nothing wrong with them. As successfully explained to BenVoigt Filemaker code is not structured the same way but it does not mean it isn't programming or a programming question.  The definition of "code" is often debated in regards to Filemaker.  We won't be bullied by a user or a moderator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flag one of your down voted posts using the "other" option and a moderator will look into it. If the votes don't trigger the serial voting script we can ask the team to manually invalidate them.

If the harassment is serious we will send a message about it and if it persists after that we will suspend the account.

There's nothing we can do about the off site contacts though.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for your answer.  I don't know what to do because I can't block the incoming mail from our site.  Generally speaking our experience here has been awesome.  I've been helped out of some really tight situations by people that want to help.  And then this.

Comment: According to [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf#comment52051_262202) by Jaydles, it does look like the StackOverflow team is sometimes willing to take on-site action for off-site messages.

Comment: Hi @ChrisF.  I'm going to forward the email to team@stackoverflow.com.  To clarify it isn't a serial voting script.  It was a down vote followed by an email sent thru our website stating that he would continue to down vote our answers.  I also edited my post to include the message.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes I know.  That is not what happened here.  We posted a comment under his answer clarifying that is not the scenario.

Comment: Of course there is something you can do about the offsite contacts.  If they are determined to be real, you can ban the user doing them.

Answer (score 21):

I am posting this because your claims here have become more and more... significant. And some are downright false, while I see no evidence for others.

The user you speak of has not acted improperly here, on this site, in any way I can see remotely related to this. You suggest there are comments from him that were deleted that would make that clear. Well, moderators can view all of a user's comments, including deleted ones, and I saw *no evidence whatsoever.* The user had perfectly polite comments/answers that you didn't like, and flagged, as "not an answer".

Through it all, the other user remained polite and professional, while you repeatedly attempted to escalate. Much as you continue to do here.

You have strongly suggested this user has committed vote fraud against you. It is publicly demonstrable that this is simply untrue, yet you have doubled down on that claim when challenged on the impression it gives.

You have suggested this user is stalking you, and have called him many inflammatory names, but your only suggestion of evidence is a single email. There is nothing on this site to back up your claim, yet you have repeatedly suggested there is.

In short; you are making statements you must know to be false, and using those statements to justify extreme hyperbole against this user. (Your very first descriptive words were, "stalker" and "notoriously".)

Finally, before I got involved, you said in a comment on one of your posts that you'd contacted the staff about them. Then proceeded to make negative statements about them... all without ever having mentioned any email.

I informed you to wait for staff to investigate. You said you were... then continued publicly calling them out. I told you again... You did it again. I told you again... You come here and make an even bigger issue out of it.

---

If the email is legit, then I hope it is taken care of appropriately. But your statements so far just aren't adding up.

Comment: this is becoming extremely convoluted.  You responded to our messages and we responded to yours using comments because there is no other way to respond to you.  You deleted our responses to you but left your responses and we didn't sit silently because your response was still there.  You told us to go to Meta so we went to Meta.  I am going to outline this timeline for you step by step so that there is no confusion over the sequence of events.

Comment: @Thesis You are not listening. You've reported it. **Now drop it and wait for the staff to respond**. Continuing to make more claims like you have won't help in the least.

Comment: Absolutely nothing that we have said has been false and up until last week we hadn't connected our website to our profile and now I regret doing it.  Under questions in our profile we asked a question titled "Filemaker Getting Record ID from Related Value in Calculated Repeating Field" which by the way is now been magically placed on HOLD.  I'm assuming by you.  For what reason I cannot even guess because the question was answered.  The question was clear and it meets all of the criteria.  But it is Filemaker and most of the SO tools don't work for asking and explaining Filemaker questions.

Comment: Okay you claimed that we made a false statement publicly so again we were responding.  You said you didn't see the deleted comments (implied that they didn't exist) so we were telling you where they were and what question they were attached to since you said you couldn't locate them.  We received 2 helpful flag bonuses for reporting those comments.  We will wait for someone to contact us assuming that will be via email.  And hopefully that will happen because I cannot forward messages from our site into spam or junkmail because then all messages from our site will go to junkmail.

Comment: @Thesis I said I could not find comments supporting what you've said about this user being harassing, stalking, notorious, etc. Because they don't exist. We have much better tools than normal users to see *all* of user's posts. The only thing you've said that I can verify is true is that the user posted a "not an answer". It was deleted, your flag accepted. And you've used that since to justify your... "thing" against this user. It is not a justification for that, or your rudeness toward them ever since.

Comment: What you are missing is the email.  That's the problem.  I forwarded it to team@stackoverflow if there is another email address that I need to send it to then please let me know.

Comment: @Thesis The email is an external thing, and [I've*] we've repeatedly told you how to deal with that. I'm talking about the claims you are making here. On this site. That is, I'm talking about *your* behavior.

Comment: I have not seen any comment from you regarding how to handle the email.  My apologies if I overlooked it so please post it here again if you would.  We are definitely removing our website from our profile after this.  Internal and external are linked in this case.  I hope that we do hear from someone because though it could be a communication issue you really don't seem to care.

Comment: @Thesis my immediately previous comment contained a typo, marked with a *. It now correctly says, "we've". And you are incorrect; I care very much about this. Hence my posting. Not agreeing with you or backing you up does not equal not caring...

Comment: Have you considered that this could be just a ruse to give name recognition to his product?  He mentioned it over *forty* times.  From where I sit, this just reads like spam.

Comment: @HansPassant That's an interesting angle I haven't thought of, though I suspect the real thing here might be related to mythical creatures afraid of fire/acid...

Comment: This entire post looks like spam and if it's true, then all possible answers are already present [in this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf). VTC as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

TL, DR : don't feed this potential troll and just ignore him.

I've personally been assaulted by a bunch of people like this on another website (unrelated to programming), it was much worse actually - they managed to get my personal phone number and started harassing me there. Even though it was very scary when it happened, they're all just stupid kids with too much free time, and besides bullshit threats and insults they can't do much harm.

The fact that this person insults you of "douchebag" without any arguments what-so-ever and that his only objective is to try to cripple your answers clearly shows that he's the same kind of stupid kid I just talked about (I can't imagine a real programmer sending such emails), so if you don't give him what he wants (he wants you to be scared and to respond to his "threats"), he'll eventually get bored and that's it.

So unless his e-mails start to get scarier (death threats, etc), just ignore him and move on.

Comment: Agreeing with the fact that this user is a douchebag, don't use the word "troll" because it's a different thing. It is being used more and more for the simplest of things, even with users you disagree with. This is just a user with anger management issues. As for the threats, should I tell you what happened years ago from a threat in a public forum?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure this user actually is a troll and wants the OP to get scared. I don't think that someone with anger management issues would take the time to fill a contact form on another site... usually it's just a bunch of downvotes cast in a matter of seconds. - Yeah, feel free to share your story if it isn't too long.

Comment: @mod & Andr: please be careful about assuming things that cannot be independently verified, especially since the allegedly "harassing" member has been called out by name. I don't know what happened off site, but what I see on site surely does not support anything said here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber my post and assumptions are based on the question (and only on the question, not on the endless comments below it) and my personal experience with a similar situation - verifying whether the question tells the truth or not is none of my business.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Andre. Sorry I can't type your name properly on my phone!

Comment: @AndrewBarber you're welcome, no problems !

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with the language used in that message, or the mechanism the user you're complaining about used to contact you, but there may be some truth to "No one should pay attention to your answers."

I checked your profile, which lists your questions and answers.  A good number of your questions are on topic, questions about jQuery.  But I can't find a single one of your answers that is about programming (the fault of the person asking the question, not yours, but why are you wasting your time responding to off-topic questions that will be deleted?)

Recommendations for shopping cart products are off-topic (there you're at fault for both question and answer).  Asking how to use database software UI is off-topic (the question doesn't involve writing stored procedures).  And you gave answers to web design questions which didn't involve any programming, too.

Answering off-topic questions is a bit of a problem, since it encourages more off-topic questions.  While there isn't a site policy to go and downvote answers like that, there's also no rule against it.  So don't rush to the conclusion that this offensive user is responsible for every downvote your answers have ever gotten.

Comment: +1, but just for my info; does your quote refer to something contradicting something I've said that I should look into?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Not contradicting anything you've said.  And the only thing you might be wanting to look into is whether you want to accelerate the process of deleting those off-topic questions.

Comment: Cool, Ben; thanks! I made some pretty definitive statements in my answer, and want to be sure I correct any error quickly, if I've made any. As for my one failing here, I think the topic might be slightly informed by their existence, for now.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I can see that point.  If they're being preserved primarily for reference from this Meta post, I suggest that one of the question locks might be apropos.

Comment: @BenVoigt when you get attacked externally because you did not accept someone's answer let me know.  How exactly are our questions not about programming?  We have just recently started answering questions and they are only in the Filemaker and Sqaurespace categories.  There is no code to post for Filemaker because it is Filemaker.  The SquareSpace question could not be answered fully because the user did not specify the template they were using so we could not provide the syntax and they never answered.  I think it's pretty obvious that we aren't going to receive any help.

Comment: @ThesisDesign: If FileMaker has no code, it may be off-topic for this site.  Or do some FileMaker questions have code (SQL and/or stored procedures), and it's this one that did not?  It's possible for some FileMaker questions to be on-topic even if that one isn't.

Comment: @BenVoigt you might be right about Filemaker not working here because it is difficult to answer Filemaker questions here because the SO tools are primarily for raw code.  But they have a group for it here and I subscribed to the emails so I could answer when I could.  Filemaker UI questions are coding questions or Filemaker's version of code.  The are inextricably linked.  At the same time people do find help here where Filemaker Desktop is concerned so deleting it really isn't fair.

Comment: @BenVoigt there is also the PHP web publishing side of Filemaker that would be closer to what I think you would deem legitimate code but I have only seen 2 or 3 questions on the PHP side.  So again deleting the Filemaker category would do more harm than good.

Comment: @BenVoigt just saw your comment about SQL and the answer is yes.  Filemaker Developers often develop Filemaker solutions with SQL, MySQL and Oracle backends...stored procedures and all.  But I have not seen anyone ask those questions here yet.  I think the Filemaker community here is just getting off the ground.

Comment: @BenVoigt I realize that most coders don't think much of Filemaker but there are some 100K solutions out there in major corporations especially in entertainment because changes can be made faster and at a lower cost to the client.  So there should be a place for it here because it is versatile and it is a largely successful application even if it isn't your thing.  But again answering questions in SO where Filemaker is concerned can be difficult because there are so many working pieces in a Filemaker solution and you can't just post straight code.  And there is no JSBin equiv for Filemaker.

Comment: @BenVoigt and since I have a stable personality I won't try to find your personal or company email and send you a nasty message because you think "No one should pay attention to my answers".  If you think Filemaker is off topic for SO it's nothing Filemaker Devs haven't heard before.  But someone asked a question and I tried to actually help them and I gain no personal fulfillment from insulting people or their careers.  In fact I'm typing this message from my apartment in Madrid so, lol, you may not like Filemaker but I do because it bought me a summer vacation home and that is REAL.

Comment: @BenVoigt Why did you delete your comments? What you're hiding?

Comment: @ThesisDesign: You seem to think that being useful is the measure of being on-topic for StackOverflow.  But it's not.  Hopefully all useful questions find a home on at least one of the StackExchange sites... but StackOverflow is only for programming.  If FileMaker is part programming and part not, perhaps it would be a better fit on the database administration site, where engine installation, database configuration, and SQL and stored procedure coding are all on-topic (at least I think so, I'm not active there).

Comment: @Moderateur: What are you talking about?  I haven't deleted any comments from this discussion.  Furthermore, your handling of this situation strikes me more and more as sockpuppet-like.  You might consider a more balanced approach here.  Or are you affiliated with ThesisDesign?

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt initially when you said off-topic I thought you meant my answer was off-topic but I realized you meant the questions in the actual category.  I didn't create the Filemaker category it was here before I arrived so it really isn't my call.  Whether Filemaker is legit or not is sort of an age-old discussion that has gone on since its inception but it's all perspective.  Filemaker has it's own code.  What I mean is it is not HTML/CSS/JavaScript and the like where everything can be viewed in a snippet.  You really have to work to answer a FMP question in here because of the tools avail

Comment: @BenVoigt Then I'm sorry for that, but I see ThesisDesign made a lot of comments one after another and that he was replying to someone. I'm not affiliated with ThesisDesign, but in this case I would be, because I see he's treated wrongly, taking into account he was harassed off-site. However bad his answers may have been it doesn't condone the other user's harassing action and the many downvotes this question has received. In fact if I was a moderator I'd already have undone them all.

Comment: lol @Moderateur thanks for sticking up.  My answers weren't bad.  The discussion now is that Filemaker is off-topic for SO therefore my answers are crap.  Really if someone isn't a Filemaker Developer they shouldn't even go there.  The same way I wouldn't start trash talking another programming language that I personally don't use or know how to.

Comment: @ThesisDesign: Please don't assume that because a tag exists here that all questions about that technology are acceptable.  To take an extreme example, consider Microsoft Office.  It has macro and OLE automation capabilities that are programming and on-topic.  But 99% of usage of MS Office is solidly off-topic.

Comment: Honestly @Moderateur it has become clear that we aren't going to get any help since now they are just looking for other reasons to take points away from us.  Filemaker is a multi-billion dollar company.  It uses PHP, SQL, MYSQL, ORACLE, XML, XSLT list goes on and on.  I don't understand who get's to decide that one piece of software is on-topic and one piece software isn't.  Honestly I don't care anymore.  This isn't a place where things are fairly assessed.  Seems more like Stalkeroverflow.

Comment: @ThesisDesign I understand that an answer or question is off-topic, but so is the discussion started by Ben Voigt and other users, because the focus was on the user's off-site harassing action. Off-topic answers or questions have nothing to do with that. It's like someone has a speech and I give my point of view (which may be something taboo) which disagrees with most of the speech's participants and goes a bit off-topic. When the speech is done the participants go and start to harass me on my way home and threaten to kick me out next time I show. Who is to blame here?

Comment: Exactly @Moderateur like I said they are just picking our account apart now.  We'll probably continue to ask questions here but we won't be answering questions because it isn't a pleasant place to participate from that angle.  Filemaker isn't off-topic really.  It was just a cheap insult but I answered like a professional.

Comment: @ThesisDesign: You're completely missing the point.  Particular software isn't either on-topic of off-topic.  Read my comment above about Office again.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, but regardless it wasn't the point of the question. This user **was stalked** off-site, why do you have to bring off-topic arguments on the table anyway? Stop picking a user's account apart and focus on the culprit for a moment. You were given the brain and limbs to open another question.

Comment: @Moderateur: One of the claims made in this Meta discussion was that the account is the target of illegitimate downvotes.  I'm explaining why some users might have downvoted, completely unrelated to the harassment.

Comment: You mean illegitimate serial downvotes maybe. But the question was really *What to do when you have a Stack Overflow Stalker*

Comment: @Moderateur: That would be one type of illegitimate downvote, yes.  Anyway, this meta question talked about behavior both on and off the site, only the team has any tools for responding to off-site behavior, but I can offer some information concerning on-site voting.

Comment: @BenVoigt I get the point but there is no comparison between MS Office and Filemaker.  There really isn't.  I've been trying to explain for about 10 comments but short of typing up the manual I don't think I'll be able to create a clear picture.  Filemaker does belong here.  More so than SquareSpace and many other things do.  There is a lot of CSS and HTML involved in Filemaker UI it's just that displaying an answer here can be difficult because in Filemaker the code is in separate places.  So one can't just paste in code snippet.  To give a truly complete answer I would have to...

Comment: There should be some sort of "purgatory" for dubious answers or questions to wait on before being published because I see there are way too many cases of controversies. With this I'm detaching from further discussion.

Comment: @BenVoigt continued.  I would have to take screenshots of the layouts, relational structures, and individual calc fields after I built them based on the users description and then scripting could probably go where the other code snippets usually go.  It doesn't really belong in Database admin because that is a different task in Filemaker.  I would compare it to SQL DEV vs SQL ADMIN jobs in an office environment.  My point is it's legit and it needs to stay and if someone takes the time to answer a Filemaker question no one should have the right to penalize them after and take their points.

Comment: @BenVoigt anyway Filemaker speaks for itself as an industry I don't really need to defend it.  If Andrew or SO want to start targeting our Filemaker questions we will reach out to the other Filemaker companies on here and we will contact someone higher up the food chain as a group.  I really need to get some work done.  Enjoy your day.

Comment: @Moderateur you've been great today and it was really nice to meet you.  I have to finish this project I'm working on so I'm going to log off of SO for now so I don't get drawn back in.  Please enjoy your day and hope to see you around the forum.

Comment: @ThesisDesign Same here :-) I did the same thing. Thanks and enjoy your day too!

Comment: "that is a different task in Filemaker"... that's all I'm saying.  FileMaker questions about programming are on topic, but that doesn't mean all FileMaker questions are.  Does FileMaker not show you the Data Definition Language describing the relations?  Just because a UI exists for creating relations, doesn't necessarily mean there's no textual representation which can be pasted in as background for the programming questions.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'll agree with that.  Not all Filemaker questions are on-topic the same way that all PHP questions aren't on-topic.  No on the relationship side Filemaker is a visual editor.  It isn't like SQL in that way.  The problem that we face with Filemaker from a Moderator standpoint in SO is that when someone who does not use Filemaker looks at a Filemaker answer or even a question they aren't always going to see the answer's relevance and will strike it down as obtuse.  To create the higher end Filemaker solutions you have to know traditional code PHP, HTML, all of that...

Comment: @ThesisDesign: Well, I fell sorry for developers having to work in an environment where the data and other stuff they have to access can't be exported/backed up in a simple plain text format.  Text makes version control work so much better.  Do you have any sort of diff tool?

Comment: @BenVoigt continued.  And you have to know relational structure.  As an example of why Filemaker needs to be here, StackOverflow is an invaluable tool because while someone might be great at Filemaker native, HTML, and CSS they may not be great at PHP.  PHP has a specific syntax as it relates to Filemaker.  And there is a whole world of people out there getting rich off of the interface.  MTV, Sony Pictures, Nickelodeon, Amgen, Disney, they all use Filemaker with SQL backends.  But in Filemaker it is all merged together like a puzzle.

Comment: lol @BenVoigt it can be difficult.  Which is why we don't develop in Filemaker full-time.  We switch between Web and large Filemaker projects.  Version control would be a dream but I don't think it will ever happen in Filemaker because they rely on the visual editor.  You have more tools when you deploy at the server level and you can run back-ups etc. but a Filemaker backup is a system backup, data and all.  You can't just roll to version back. Also the new Filemaker server is expensive.  They have adopted the SQL licensing model so we are seeing a drop off in mid-sized business using it.

Comment: @BenVoigt It really all depends on the budget and needs of the client.  large entertainment companies like Filemaker because of the speed of development.  Mid-sized companies like it because of the price tag.  In other environments we develop traditional SQL/Web solutions because they have the money and they want to commit to the solution in the long term.  Anyhow, again enjoy your day.

Comment: @ThesisDesign: You have a good day as well.  And your coworkers too.