# Is there a way to block a Stack Overflow user?

Tags: discussion, users

There are a **lot** of people on here with serious ego problems, and I have been having increasing problems lately with people getting upset that I mark their answers as wrong, then stalking me and going around downvoting everything I do on this site. I need a way to block users so that they can't take their ignorance out on me.

Comment: It takes some time to take effect, but StackOverflow has serial downvote/upvote detection. Give it a few days, and you'll see the mass down-votes reverted

Comment: If a user is harassing you then you can raise a mod flag.

Comment: (sort-of) Happened to me lately as well. To be able to "target" you, you must have commented. I learned the hard way to try and reduce that. By simply down-voting posts you already provide implicit feedback and doesn't necessarily need to comment as well. This will greatly reduce the chances of someone "targeting" you (as votes are of course anonymous)

Comment: It is worth noting that if you block me I'm also unable to upvote your well received content. Is that a side-effect you're happy with?

Comment: "_I mark their answers as wrong_" How do you do that? Or do you mean downvote?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270229/what-to-do-when-you-have-a-stack-overflow-stalker

Comment: @Adalcar it is in your own best interest to take grains of salt with a rene.

Comment: Bryan, as it seems you know who *exactly* is targeting you (which I am not sure how, but let's say it is possible), please *do* report them by flagging a post and explaining the reasoning why you think you are being harassed (but be sure you have proof and not just a hunch). P.s. Unless you delete content as soon as it gets downvoted, there is nothing in your [rep history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11244339/bryan-williams?tab=reputation&sort=time) that suggests stalking.

Comment: I think feedback is nice even if it's saying something is not working. I'll comment on someone's post if I think something is wrong with it, and I sometimes get positive feedback from it, or mostly no feedback at all. Perhaps it depends on the nature of the feedback and how it's phrased?

Comment: Just in case - be aware of this: [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686)

Comment: Maybe it's your tone? I've just read one of your answers about FileSystemWatcher and you appear to get on your high horse pretty quickly, attacking SO users in general when you're not happy about something. Calm down a bit.

Comment: I should have expected that simply posting this question has triggered people to start harassing me, lol. The irony in the air is thick today.

Comment: @BryanWilliams - Your attitude towards the community could be dramatically improved.  You have literally received a single downvote in the last 3 months.  I see absolutely no downvotes on anything in 2020 until March 2020.  **So not a single one of your answers have been downvoted in the last year.**  If you are talking about deleted questions and answers, well if they received downvotes, and are deleted then they were not helpful.

Comment: "start harassing me" how? Do you know that meta votes reasons include agreeing/disagreeing & that (other than at [meta.se] it has no effect on your rep?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for making us aware of potential problems on Stack Overflow.

> There are a lot of people on here with serious ego problems

Call it ego or call it proud or inexperienced or not seen the light yet. But if we want to address this at all, it needs some examples of what a serious ego problem looks like, because it is hard to have a mutual correct understanding of serious problems.

> I have been having increasing problems lately with people getting upset that I mark their answers as wrong

Getting upset is not a very productive emotion. I think it is perfectly fine 'to mark answers wrong' by any method you use for that. Preferable a downvote as that is a strong signal to future visitors, and leave a comment if you feel like it, but that is not mandatory at all. If you still feel your assessment of a post is correct even after your call is challenged then simply move on. There is no requirement on the site that you're held responsible or are required to make the same judgement call as all other users.

> then stalking me and going around downvoting everything I do on this site.

Serial downvoting is detected by the system and reversed after 24 or 48 hours. If downvotes are left in retaliation and are without doubt targeted, but not reversed, flag one of your posts for moderation attention and explain clearly why the votes on your post are not cast due to users stumbling on your posts. Moderators can escalate to SE staff to investigate voting against your content.

> I need a way to block users so that they can't take their ignorance out on me.

Well, that might solve your problem, but not the unacceptable behavior from the blocked user. They continue their unruly behavior making the life on the site for other users unbearable. A better approach is to document the misbehaving, use the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) as a behavioral base line and then flag the troublesome exchanges for a moderator. That might not give immediate results, but if you've found a pattern and that pattern becomes more clear over time it is more likely that users get warned and suspended.

We can only make Stack Overflow an inclusive and safe site if we do not tolerate off-limits behavior, but we need eyes on the ground to spot these few individuals that try to spoil the fun for many. Blocking users doesn't help in that sense. Reporting their behavior does.

Comment: In effect, there is a way to block a user who has actually violated the code of conduct: Its called getting them suspended by a moderator, and any such offensive content deleted from the site.

Comment: @user1937198 true that. If every user that wanted to block me had led to my suspension I think I would still be serving jail time ...

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're discussing would have the effect of preventing someone from downvoting your posts entirely, which is inconsistent with the site's moderation model.

That being said, targeting other users for revenge downvoting is also inconsistent with the site's moderation model. Others have pointed this out, but if you know who's doing it raise a custom flag explaining the situation. Otherwise, you can use the contact form to ask SE to look into it. If someone is behaving inappropriately in this way, they should be suspended for abusing the voting system.