# What to do when someone keeps serial-upvoting me?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, harassment

Similar to [What to do when I feel that someone is stalking me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269172/what-to-do-when-i-feel-that-someone-is-stalking-me)

There's a guy that got banned from SO after it was discovered that he had multiple accounts and used them to down-vote people he didn't like. This happened in the comment-section of one of my answers (should be easy to find for any moderator.)

Since that incident someone serial-upvotes a handful of my answers every week or so. I think it is that same guy -- as a matter of fact I'm almost certain it is him.

The serial voting gets reversed every time but as it is recurring I'm afraid that it will have consequences on my account. What should I do? Is there something I can do when I notice that I have been serial-upvoted?

Comment: Side note: What if you're within some type of corporate environment  operating under one IP with, say, over 100 developers. 50 of them happen to stumble across one of my answers/questions; find it useful; then upvotes?

Comment: @Shaz YOu should pose that as a meta question.

Comment: @Shaz as far as I know sock-puppetry isn't punished by anything other than the removal of the votes so you don't risk a ban but I'm sure all the votes will be reversed.

Comment: you seem to be out rightly honest...!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The system has reversed those votes.  Letting us know via a flag allows us to intervene if it keeps happening.  We may not tell you what we'll do, but it's good to let us know in instances where it keeps happening and the individual shows no signs of stopping.

This issue has been taken care of. If it  happens in the future, please flag one of your own posts that received one of these votes and let us know:

> User *X* is upvoting|downvoting my account repeatedly. These votes are being reversed by the system, but this user keeps doing it.

The subject is discussed at length on the main meta site, see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: It should be added that nothing bad is going to happen to your account just because someone is serially upvoting your posts. The system may roll back those votes, but it doesn't leave a black mark against you or hurt you in any way. It requires human intervention to warn or suspend someone for voting fraud, and we need to see more evidence than just votes going from one person to another. Someone's not going to trick us into suspending you just because they voted for you.

Comment: Does the rep cap reached (and reversed) by serial upvoting count to earning *Earned 200 daily reputation for...* badges ?

Comment: @TLama You raise a good question: is the serial upvoter doing it 'to be nice', or are they really intending to max-out the daily reputation limit for the OP to give them a bad time? The second option seems more likely.

Comment: @TLama You should pose that as a meta question.

Comment: @TLama Apparently the SE staff was wise enough to avoid that particular conundrum. I think the section titled "Reversals trigger a reputation recalculation" in this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/215123) should give you the details you're looking for.

Comment: @TLama you'll get your points back and may even get badge if it is the last day of hitting max rep... Even covered on [English language & usage SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203755/expression-for-losing-something-that-you-never-really-had/203817#203817) as part of "how to refer to reputation points not obtained due to the cap".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker he's managed to circumvent the reversing, I flagged one of my own posts as you said but no one seems to have seen that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I suspect I'm a "victim" of serial upvotes, but while nothing bad is going to happen to my account as you stated, should I notify a moderator anyway, or only if the user keeps doing so?

Answer (score 24):

From [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me):

> **Should I be concerned about reversal statements on my profile?**
>
> No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After
>   all, we can't control the actions of other users. It's very rare where
>   we'd run across a user who was committing the voting fraud themselves
>   on their own account, and in most instances of that, they will have
>   already been dealt with accordingly. You should in no way be concerned
>   with reversal statements in your reputation history.

If it gets *really* bad you could flag a moderator via one of the posts (especially if its the same one each time):

> Continual abuse of the system which causes multiple reversals can lead
>   to a suspension, but the review process for such a suspension is
>   completely manual. No automated flags are ever generated for this
>   behavior, though moderators do have access to some statistics that can
>   help fight repeat offenders. If you find you are the victim of serial
>   voting multiple times within a short time span, feel free to flag one
>   of your posts for moderator attention and explain the situation so
>   they can investigate further.

Basically, if it happens a few times, ignore it, a bunch of times, flag a moderator.

Answer (score 10):

It won't have a negative impact on your account as long as you aren't involved. If you're worried about it, flag one of your posts with an `other` flag explaining what's happening and a moderator will take a look.

Answer (score 9):

Posting here was a correct course of action, although I'd simply either flag one of my posts for moderator attention, explaining the situation, or [contact Stack Exchange Staff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) directly.

Don't worry about it though. The serial votes get reversed, and you've brought this to attention.