# Serial upvoting by one user?

Tags: support, serial-voting

It might be the boring question
One user is upvoting me all answer,
One day he did this and now today again he upvotes my all answer.

I Know the reversal system and correction of reputation on serial voting.

**How can I block such user?**

**Is there any way I can complain about this?**

Because I don't want such user to upvoting the on regular base.

I know that the next day StackOverflow will make it proper.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for letting us know about this. I've had a quick word with the offending user. If this continues, please feel free to flag for our attention again.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I block such user?

**AFAIK** that is not possible.
You can not  block a particular user.

> Is there any way I can complain about this?

**YES**

FROM this answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275005/7666442

*If it happens in the future, please flag one of your own posts that received one of these votes*

For more information Please read this [What to do when someone keeps serial-upvoting me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275001/what-to-do-when-someone-keeps-serial-upvoting-me)

**NOTE :** Don't worry about Serial upvotes, serial votes get reversed