# Co-worker keeps upvoting me—what to do?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I have this co-worker that is new to Stack Overflow, and he upvotes me, pretty much agreeing on anything I post, I tried to be nice to him and explained that this could lead an issue to our accounts, and he should only upvote me if he found something 100% useful for him.

And he replied that he finds everything I post useful since he is only a fresh.

The question here could this lead to a problem on my account or his?

Since we are in the same company we use the static IP address.

I can't prevent him from upvoting...

Comment: Yow, Mohmmad S's coworker. Stop upvoting all his stuff. Bring him coffee instead to show thanks.

Comment: Tell him that both of your accounts will incur problems if he doesn't stop targeting your posts with upvotes. Firmly tell him to stop 100% because you never know when you will trip the ban.

Comment: I understand that this is a legitimate problem, but this story is still legitimately heartwarming.

Comment: Coming from a Workplace-esque perspective, I recommend that you explain two things to your new coworker: 1) what they are doing can get you (and them) in trouble and that spreading the votes around is good and 2) you are not always right, and not everyone on SO is always right. We do our best to filter the good from the bad, but everyone here is learning.

Comment: @JonHarper thats the point,

Comment: If you identify their account then a moderator may be willing to send them a warning message so that they understand the seriousness of the situation. Not sure if you should identify them in this post but maybe in a custom moderator flag on one of your questions.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yeah i will flag my posts to a mod if anything heppens  in the future,

Comment: @MohmmadS I wouldn't wait for the future because you might be banned by then. I definitely recommend taking as many proactive steps as needed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i am leaving the company

Comment: @MohmmadS So, your Stack Overflow could be banned after your leave the company. What if they continue to upvote after you leave?

Comment: like, what should i do .... flag his account to a mod ?

Comment: You cannot flag an account directly. Get their account's URL and flag one of your posts for custom moderator attention and explain the situation and provide your co-worker's account.

Comment: the joke is one the mods is a close friend of mine he also sometimes open from the same wifi as i ... lol

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i refuse to tell him as he would mock me xD since i am just noob

Comment: That's cool. Just follow my instructions and good luck.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus hopefully thanks for commenting have a good day

Comment: I approve of the passive aggressiveness of this post. "How do I get this person to leave me alone?" said loudly in a forum they frequent.

Comment: @KGVT I wonder if they upvoted this post...

Comment: You have a lot of answers with zero score for someone with a sock puppet account that upvotes everything you write. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo perhaps i mean whenever he gets the chance also i didnt say sock puppet account, i said co-worker who ever that get the chance to or see post , apparently he doesn't know the site very well yet since he behave like this

Comment: @MohmmadS: I was typing in jest. But really, this doesn’t look like something to worry about, your coworker doesn’t upvote *everything*, just occasionally something. This is what voting is about. Seems correct and normal to me.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yeah but some mods could not see that, and the automatic ban system ..

Answer (score 69, accepted):

***No, you will not be suspended for being the recipient of targeted votes, whether up or down.***

While an IP match is something we take into account when investigating sock puppets and voting rings, we don't treat it as a smoking gun.

You may be contacted or suspended if:

- We're 100% certain the two accounts belong to the same person.
- We see targeted voting from *you* to your co-worker.

I've had a look into your situation, and while I believe I've identified the person you're talking about, there doesn't appear to be evidence of an up-voting spree. At least, not to the extent that we'd intervene.

---

As a general answer though; if you believe you're being serially upvoted (whether or not it's from a co-worker), *please* raise a flag for investigation. Doubly so if you believe the votes are coming from a matching IP address. People deliberately trying to abuse the voting system won't typically ask a moderator to investigate their account; so it's highly unlikely a moderator will mistakenly take action against your account.

If we find evidence of targeted voting, the person casting the votes will be contacted if necessary. ***No action will be taken against  your account***, aside from having the votes reversed if deemed to be fraudulent.

Comment: "People deliberately trying to abuse the voting system won't typically ask a moderator to investigate their account" Let's hope people who are trying to abuse the voting system don't see this, otherwise they'd get the idea to start raising flags to avoid suspicion. :p

Comment: @coldspeed Well, we'd *still* have the votes reversed if necessary - flag or not - so it's not too productive for them anyway ;)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you could get suspended for a certain amount of time (time depends on how bad the fraud is) due to voting irregularities, that will make you have only 1 rep and unable to post for a amount of time, look at the below links:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

["This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/this-account-is-temporarily-suspended-for-voting-irregularities)

It does lead to a problem, especially with same IP addresses.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there anyway that i can prevent him from upvoting ... like blocking mechanic or something ..

Comment: @MohmmadS Sorry, but currently it isn't possible, see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369655/serial-upvoting-by-one-user

Comment: @MohmmadS I think the best way would be to tell your co-worker to stop up-voting and also tell him that he can get a suspension due to voting irregularities, and I think he will stop due to being afraid of getting suspended.

Comment: i will probably explain that to him ... @U9-Forward .. and ill flag my questions/ answers if it continues to happen .

Comment: @MohmmadS Hope that helps and stops him from serial voting :-)

Comment: hopefully ,, i worked hard for my account .. i wouldn't like to get banned at any point ..

Comment: @MohmmadS Of course :-) no one would like to :P

Comment: @MohmmadS Why not just show your coworker this meta thread?

Comment: i will actually